# How to edit elements simultaneously on all artboards in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, artboard

I have several artboards in Photoshop on every artboard placed text, how change color of this text only in one place that the changes are applied to all texts on artboards?

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking here. Can you please try to rephrase your question to make it clearer exactly what it is you’re trying to achieve? Please also include what you’ve tried that didn’t work—and screenshots are always useful.

Comment: If you make the text into a smart object, then you can place/copy it on to any other artboard. By editing and saving the smart object, the changes will be applied to all instances of that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your text. (or create whatever object it is you want to create)

Convert the text layer to a **Smart Object**.

Copy and place that smart object where you want it (on various artboards).

To change the color on one artboard, add a **Color Overlay Layer Style** to *that* smart object.

To change the text across all artboards, double click one of the smart objects and edit the original text layer.

Comment: And you can link layers across multiple artboards so that in addition to editing the source smart layer, you can change the positioning of all of the smart layer instances simultaneously.